# Flex dynamically when orientation changes (flip device)

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-stylesheet

I'm not ready to lock my app in portrait mode yet, not until I'm sure we can't figure this out.

There once was a container called `SwipeListView`. It's a third party package, if you don't know it you can check this snack: [`react-native-swipe-list-view`](https://snack.expo.io/@jemise111/react-native-swipe-list-view).
It's working, but the back layer of each row doesn't stretch to the full width of the screen when 
I flip my device (portrait -> landscape)

[image]
[image]

The list item itself stretches fine, but the back layer (with the buttons) sticks to its' original width.
Here's the `SwipeListView` with it's `renderItem` for the item data and `renderHiddenItem` for the back layer for each row:

```
<SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}>
    <SwipeListView
        keyExtractor={Child.keyExtractor}
        data={this.props.children}
        renderItem={(itemInfo, rowMap) => {
            return <ChildListItem child={itemInfo.item}
                onPress={() => console.log("Row pressed: ", itemInfo)} />
        }}
        renderHiddenItem={(itemInfo, rowMap) => {
            return <ChildListHiddenItem child={itemInfo.item}
                onEdit={() => this.props.openEditChildDialog(true, itemInfo.item.id)}
                onDelete={() => this.props.openDeleteChildDialog(true)} />
        }}
        onRowDidOpen={rowKey => console.log(`Row with key ${rowKey} openend`)}
        leftOpenValue={75}
        rightOpenValue={-75}
        previewRowKey={'0'}
        previewOpenValue={-40}
        previewOpenDelay={3000}
    />
</SafeAreaView>
```

For the sake of the length, I'm going to spare you the `ChildListItem`. This is the `ChildListHiddenItem`:

```
class CChildListHiddenItem
extends Component<IChildListHiddenItemProps>
implements ComponentLifecycle<IChildListHiddenItemProps, {}> {
    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps: Readonly<IStyleState>, nextState: Readonly<IStyleState>, nextContext: any): boolean {
        return this.props.orientation !== nextProps.orientation;
    }

    render() {
        const {
            child,
            style,
            onDelete,
            onEdit,
            ...viewProps
        } = this.props;
        return(

            <LinearGradient
                style={[
                    styles.containers.listHiddenItem,
                    {flexBasis: this.props.dimensions.width}, \\ <----- OVER HERE
                    // orientationAwareStyles.apply.flexBasisFull,
                    style
                ]}
                colors={['red','transparent', 'green']}
                start={{x: 0, y: .5}} end={{x: 1, y: .5}}
                locations={[0.1,0.5,0.9]}
                {...viewProps}
            >
                <Buttons.ListDelete onPress={onDelete} />{/* iconName="user-minus" */}
                <Buttons.ListEdit onPress={onEdit} />{/* iconName="user-edit" */}
            </LinearGradient>
        )
    }
}
const mapStateToChildListHiddenItemProps = ((state:IStore) => {
    return {
        orientation: state.style.orientation,
        dimensions: state.style.dimensions,
    };
});

// @ts-ignore
export const ChildListHiddenItem = connect<IStore>(mapStateToChildListHiddenItemProps, null)(CChildListHiddenItem);
```

And the StyleSheet property that is applied:

```
listHiddenItem: {
    flex:1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexBasis: dimWindow.width,
    flexWrap: "nowrap",
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    height: 50,
},
```

I'm going to spare you the logic for updating `this.props.dimensions` too because I have confirmed that this value is updated correctly by placing a breakpoint in the render function.

Any ideas or past experiences?

PS: In case you need it:

> Binaries:
>     Node: 13.9.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
>     npm: 6.13.7 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
>   IDEs:
>     Android Studio: Version  3.6.0.0 AI-192.7142.36.36.6241897
>   npmPackages:
>     react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0
>     react-native: ^0.61.5 => 0.61.5

### Attempt update

```
<View
    style={[
        styles.containers.listHiddenItem,
        {flexBasis: this.props.dimensions.width},
        // orientationAwareStyles.apply.flexBasisFull,
        style
    ]}
    {...viewProps}
>
    <Buttons.ListDelete onPress={onDelete} />{/* iconName="user-minus" */}
    <LinearGradient
        style={{flex:1, flexGrow:1}}
        colors={['red','transparent', 'green']}
        start={{x: 0, y: .5}} end={{x: 1, y: .5}}
        locations={[0.1,0.5,0.9]}
    />
    <Buttons.ListEdit onPress={onEdit} />{/* iconName="user-edit" */}
</View>
```

The `LinearGradient` moved down one level, using `flexGrow` and `flexShrink` still doesn't help which proves that it's the container that's not updated with the new `flexBasis`